# python3 path.join TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python code breaks in python3.

Vectorize.py contains the following line

```
path = os.path.join('..', path[:-1])
```

Error output:

```
$ python3 vectorize_text.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vectorize_text.py", line 46, in <module>
    path = os.path.join('..', path[:-1])
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
"components") from None
TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path component
```

On the other hand, running in python2.7 it works fine. What am I missing here ? Is the command different ? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Udacity Intro to Machine Learning, for anyone who comes looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `path` is a *`bytes`* object, not a `str` string. You can then only use more `bytes` strings to make a different path. Use a `b'..'` `bytes` literal:

```
path = os.path.join(b'..', path[:-1])
```

Comment: @vaultah: indeed. I'm trying to do too many things at once today.