# Trouble using Javabridge with Python

Tags: python, path, php-java-bridge

I successfully installed javabridge using `$pip3 install javabridge` on my Mac's virtual environment. But when I tried to import javabridge in my python3 code, this is what I get:

```
import javabridge

Failed to run /usr/libexec/java_home, defaulting to best guess for Java
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/puifai/Documents/data_science/venv/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/javabridge/locate.py", line 45, in find_javahome
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), "Libraries"),
  File "/Users/puifai/Documents/data_science/venv/venv3/bin/../lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 92, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/Users/puifai/Documents/data_science/venv/venv3/bin/../lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 151, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components") from None
TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? It looks like a problem with Python rather than javabridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pardon the less-than-complete answer, but it has to do with the difference in strings between Python2 and Python3. Working in Python2.7 will at least get you around the problem for the moment. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088419/python3-path-join-typeerror) for more background.